# Converting time string into Date object

Tags: javascript

I'm using timepicker and it requires a date object. From database I'm getting a time string like "17:00:00". How can I convert a time string like "17:00:00" into date object?

***Edit***
I have already tried the solution in question suggested by Mike C, Alex K but in that question they are converting a date string into a date object and when I try to convert time string into date I get an invalid date error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with dates you can write your own parser or try already proven libraries like http://momentjs.com (what I would suggest to do).

Comment: I'm trying to use moment to convert  date like that moment(schedule.StartTime).format('hh:mm:ss'); but i get invalid date error.

Comment: Because the format of your string is a bit specific, you have to specify parse rule e.g. `moment(schedule.StartTime, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss');` assuming `schedule.StartTime ~ '17:00:00'`

Comment: How on earth is this the selected answer?

Answer (score 8):

```js
var a = "17:00"
var b = toDate(a,"h:m")
alert(b);
function toDate(dStr,format) {
 var now = new Date();
 if (format == "h:m") {
   now.setHours(dStr.substr(0,dStr.indexOf(":")));
   now.setMinutes(dStr.substr(dStr.indexOf(":")+1));
   now.setSeconds(0);
   return now;
 }else 
  return "Invalid Format";
}
```

Comment: Kurenai I had to tweak your answer a little bit to make it work but in the end I had to use moment.